# How to get the project when right-click on a project/file/others in an eclipse-plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm write a simple eclipse plugin, but have a problem: When user right-click on a node(maybe a project, a file, a java compilation unit, or others), I want to get the project it belongs.

The sample code is:

```
public class MyAction implements IObjectActionDelegate {
    private IProject project;
    public void selectionChanged(IAction action, ISelection selection) {
         this.project = getSelectedProject(selection);
    }

    public static IProject getSelectedProject(Object obj) throws Exception {
        if (obj == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (obj instanceof IResource) {
            return ((IResource) obj).getProject();
        } else if (obj instanceof IStructuredSelection) {
            return getSelectedProject(((IStructuredSelection) obj).getFirstElement());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

It works at most of time, but sometimes, for example, I right-clicked on a java file, the selection will be a `ICompilationUnit`. Although I can add one more `if` in the `getSelectedProject`, but I don't think it's a good idea.

Is there a way to get the project of selected objects nomatter what have been selected? I don't want to add them one by one.

Comment: I don't see any other way in this scenario.  I don't know of one specific superclass or super-interface that you could depend on every single object coming in to use that instead of if/else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ICompilationUnit extends IAdaptable (see http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsmhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/ICompilationUnit.html)

You can try and use the IAdaptable interface like that:

```
if (obj instanceof IAdaptable) {
    IResource res = (IResource)(((IAdaptable)obj).getAdapter(IResource.class));
    if (res != null) {
        return res.getProject();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no way to convert an `ICompilationUnit`, `IPackage`, or whatever, to an `IResource` as there are most often *no* corresponding resource! E.g. for the `.class` elements in the navigator, the element corresponds to an entry in a JAR file or in a dependency plug-in from the target platform.

Answer (score 0):

it up answer don't work, may it should be:

```
    if (obj instanceof IStructuredSelection) {
        IStructuredSelection selection1 = (IStructuredSelection)obj;
        Object element = selection1.getFirstElement();
        IProject project = null;
        if (element instanceof IProject) {
            project = (IProject) element;
        } else if (element instanceof IAdaptable) {
            project = (IProject) ((IAdaptable) element).getAdapter(IProject.class);
        }
        if (project != null) {
            return project;
        }
    }
```